# BLE , Subscribe to 2 Characterisitics notification didn't work. work only for one

Tags: android, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, characteristics

i succeed to write a code for my android app which aims to read a characteristic value from my BLE device and then active the notification related to this characteristic in order top display the updated value in my app. 
the app work well.

but when i tried to active the notification for a second characteristic, the notification work only for one characteristic and not for both.

so let's call the first characteristic **'Date_time_Characteristic'** and the second one **'nbr_sample_Characteristic'**.

what i notice is the following : if i subscribe the notification of **'Date_time_Characteristic'** and then i subscribe  the **'nbr_sample_Characteristic'** only the first one subscribed will generate a notification. which is in this case the **'Date_time_Characteristic'**.

```
            // set notification for Date time Characteristic
        Console.WriteLine("Charac Uuid =  " + _charac_DateTime.Uuid);
        BluetoothLEManager.Current.ConnectedDevices[App.Current.State.SelectedDevice].SetCharacteristicNotification(_charac_DateTime, true);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = _charac_DateTime.GetDescriptor(Descr_UUID);
        Console.WriteLine("descriptor : " + descriptor.Uuid);
        descriptor.SetValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.EnableNotificationValue.ToArray());
        BluetoothLEManager.Current.ConnectedDevices[App.Current.State.SelectedDevice].WriteDescriptor(descriptor);


        // set notification for nbr sample Characteristic
        BluetoothLEManager.Current.ConnectedDevices[App.Current.State.SelectedDevice].SetCharacteristicNotification(_charac_NbrSample, true);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor2 = _charac_NbrSample.GetDescriptor(Descr_UUID);
        descriptor2.SetValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.EnableNotificationValue.ToArray());
        BluetoothLEManager.Current.ConnectedDevices[App.Current.State.SelectedDevice].WriteDescriptor(descriptor2);
```

if i do the opposite and subscribe the **'nbr_sample_Characteristic'** first , only the **'nbr_sample_Characteristic'** will generate notification and update it's value.

```
            // set notification for nbr sample Characteristic
        BluetoothLEManager.Current.ConnectedDevices[App.Current.State.SelectedDevice].SetCharacteristicNotification(_charac_NbrSample, true);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor2 = _charac_NbrSample.GetDescriptor(Descr_UUID);
        descriptor2.SetValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.EnableNotificationValue.ToArray());
        BluetoothLEManager.Current.ConnectedDevices[App.Current.State.SelectedDevice].WriteDescriptor(descriptor2);

        // set notification for Date time Characteristic
        Console.WriteLine("Charac Uuid =  " + _charac_DateTime.Uuid);
        BluetoothLEManager.Current.ConnectedDevices[App.Current.State.SelectedDevice].SetCharacteristicNotification(_charac_DateTime, true);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = _charac_DateTime.GetDescriptor(Descr_UUID);
        Console.WriteLine("descriptor : " + descriptor.Uuid);
        descriptor.SetValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.EnableNotificationValue.ToArray());
        BluetoothLEManager.Current.ConnectedDevices[App.Current.State.SelectedDevice].WriteDescriptor(descriptor);
```

how can i resolve this problem and let both characteristic notify the app ?

Comment: Are you sure the notification is really not generated by the app? Maybe it IS generated, but your callback function does not handle it properly?

Comment: normally the callback function work well i'll post the code of the call back function later when i go home.

so if the callback wasn't correct why if change the order of the charateristic subscription the notification change. so i think there is something that i miss to make between the subcription of both characteristic.

may be after i call the WriteDescriptor(); i have to wait until the writting is done. like when i try to read characteristic.

i'll try to add delay between the two sbscription and see if it work !

Comment: That might well be the reason. The response from writing the CCCD should be received before issuing the next write request. Don't add a delay, but wait for the corresponding response and issue the next request only after having received the response.

Comment: when i use the handler OnDescriptorWrite() to wait until the first descriptor is writting, now the opposite happen and only the second characteristic subscribed will generate a notification.  Weird.

I found an another thread of people having the same issue as me but unfortunately they didn't show the solution.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64404/is-it-possible-to-enable-multiple-ble-characteristic-notifications-as-once

Comment: Now that is really weird. I would modify the program as follows: Configure the first characteristic for notification. Wait for the response with OnDescriptorWrite. Then check if notifications from the first characteristic arrive. Afterwards configure the second characteristic for notification as well, wait for the response, and check if the notifications from the first characteristic stop. It smells like a notification handling mistake from your software. Maybe also show the code where the notifcation callback is handled.